# In x86/x86_64, how can I "jump if not zero" without affecting the carry flag?

Tags: loops, assembly, x86, compare, x86-64

I have this loop that essentially adds two dynamic-width integers (in reality, it is unrolled a bit, but that does not matter here). Register `RCX` contains the destination address, `RDX` contains the source address, and `R8` contains the length of the arrays.

```
    clc                    # Clear CF flag before beginning
.Lloop0:
    movq    (%rdx), %rax   # Load memory for next addition
    adcq    %rax, (%rcx)   # Perform addition with carry (i.e. using CF flag)
    leaq    8(%rcx), %rcx  # Increment destination address (without affecting CF)
    leaq    8(%rdx), %rdx  # Increment source address (without affecting CF)
    leaq    -1(%r8), %r8   # Decrement length (without affecting CF)
    testq   %r8, %r8       # Test if length is zero (affects CF!)
    jne     Lloop0
```

The problem is that the `TEST` instruction clears the `CF` flag, which is needed by the next `ADC`. The `CMP` instruction would also have a similar effect.

I could of course copy the `FLAGS` register using `LAHF` before the test and restore it using `SAHF` at the beginning of the loop, but I would like to avoid that if there is a way around it.

Comment: You can use `dec %r8`, but note that's not recommended exactly because not updating `CF` causes a partial flags register stall :)

Comment: @Jester: How does that test if it is zero?

Comment: It sets `ZF` automatically. You can just do `dec %r8; jnz Lloop0`.

Comment: Alternatively, you could rewrite the code to use `rcx` as counter and then use the `loop` instruction (which is also not recommended, but less bad than `dec` :))

Comment: @Jester: I get it. Since my loop is unrolled, I guess instead of decrementing by the number of unrolls, I should just divide (i.e. shift) it at the beginning and then just decrement by one with `DEC`.

Comment: @Jester: If I put the `DEC` before the `LEA`s, would that fix the stall? Also, why is `LOOP` not recommended?

Comment: The stall is because `dec` will have to wait for `adc`, so no, moving it up will not help. Moving it far away from the `adc` would. `LOOP` is not recommended because it is a complex instruction: `Assembly/Compiler Coding Rule 31. (M impact, M generality) Avoid using complex instructions (for example, enter, leave, or loop) that have more than four µops and require multiple cycles to decode. Use sequences of simple instructions instead.`

Comment: @Jester: So the `JNZ` would not have to wait for the `DEC`?

Comment: Of course it has to, that's a true dependency. Since you are looping the only disadvantage is that the `dec` can not run in parallel with the `adc`.

Comment: @Jester: What I meant was does `JNZ` have to wait for `DEC` to completely finish before it can start? In other words, will there be bubbles in the pipeline between `JNZ` and `DEC`?

Comment: x86 cpus are complicated beasts. The `JNZ` will be speculatively executed based on branch prediction, so if you loop many times, it should be efficient.

Comment: You can also use `rcx` (instead of `r8`) as your counter and the `loop` instruction. The `loop` instruction implicitly uses `rcx` as the counter and does not affect the carry flag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can swap the roles of `%r8` and `%rcx` above to yield:

```
    clc
    .p2align 4 # just a thought...
.Lloop0:
    jrcxz .Lloop0_end
    ...
    leaq  -1(%rcx), %rcx
    jmp   .Lloop0
.Lloop0_end:
```

Comment: There wouldn't happen to be something like `JRCXNZ`, that would jump if `RCX` is *not* zero?

Comment: No, that doesn't exist, @matt. But there is virtually no reason to ever use `jrcxz` or the mythical `jrcxnz`. It is slower than breaking the instructions up into two.